# How to get weather data for specific date using wunderground

Tags: javascript, json, api, weather-api, wunderground

This is the first time I am using this `wunderground`.I want to get weather data as per following cases

Note : Today Date :2014-02-03

1. I want to get weather data from 2014-01-21 to 2014-01-31 so it's comes to history data.
2. I want to get weather data from 2014-02-05 to 2014-02-07. so it's comes to forecast data.

I searched `wunderGround` documentation, but I didn't found arguments for making API call for specific dates.

I found the following links for both history and forecast data.but I don't know How to specify particular date limits in the request.

history link:

`http://api.wunderground.com/api/4d474af3da6c8f65/history_20140121/q/CA/bangalore.json`

forecast link:

`http://api.wunderground.com/api/4d474af3da6c8f65/forecast/q/CA/bangalore.json`

forecast :

I can't able to specify the date,that's why I am not able to get the data for specific dates.What I want,data from `2014-02-05` to `2014-04-07`.

history :

I can't able to specify endDate in api call.

can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Weather Underground history API ([docs](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/history)) is only available for a single date at a time. The solution is to build your code into a loop and increment the date in each iteration. You are also limited to 10 calls per minute and 500 per day on the free package so this won't help if you need results quickly or a lot of results, but they do have [premium packages available at a cost](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/pricing.html).