# How to download historical weather data using Wunderground API?

Tags: java, wunderground

Is it possible to download historical weather data using Java from Wunderground API between two specific dates for a specific location ?

From this link, it says that only available for a single date at a time.
[How to get weather data for specific date using wunderground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523234/how-to-get-weather-data-for-specific-date-using-wunderground)

If it is not possible, are there any other alternatives which I can do so using Java ?

Comment: Why don't you ask them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one: http://openweathermap.com/api. It's free and it gives you a good amount of API calls per minute and per day.